# Prevent ggplot from auto-adjusting facet sizes in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this problem where R will auto-adjust the size of the facets in ggplot. In the 2 attached images, clearly, the one scaled from 0-100 on the y-axis is less stretched out compared to the one scaled at 6.6-7.2. These are plotted using the same ggplot commands from maaply, so I don't know where the difference would come from. Is there any way to prevent R from performing the auto-adjusting to keep the formatting of each ggplot the same? My OCD and I thank you.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does `ylim(x,y)` or `coord_cartesian(ylim=c(x,y))` not work here?

Comment: The axis limits are not the issue. I've tried adjusting, and the scale is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like I have made a copy and paste error where I used some the the wrong variable to set the base_height in save_plot within mapply, so the scaling factor was varying across iterations.

Comment: Always good to answer your own question when you do have the answer.  Can you please modify your question (or answer) to show where the coding error happened?  This will make the question more useful as a resource for future coders.  Thanks!